# Regular Expression (preg_match_all) and array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, preg-match, preg-match-all

This is the Code:

```
   <?php
    $matchWith = "# http://videosite.com/id1 http://videosite.com/id2 # # http://videosite.com/id3 http://videosite.com/id4 #";

    preg_match_all('%(#)\shttp://videosite\.com/(\w+)\r{0,1}\shttp://videosite\.com/(\w+)\r{0,1}\s(#)%', $matchWith, $result);
    foreach($result[2] as $value)
    {  
    print '<a href="http://videosite.com/'.$value.'">
    First Part
    </a>';        

    }  
    foreach($result[3] as $value)
    {  
    print '<a href="http://videosite.com/'.$value.'">
    Second Part
    </a>';        
    }
    ?>
```

The Problem:

I want it to display like this: First Part, Second Part and First Part Second Part.

But it displays it like this: First Part, First Part, Second Part, Second Part.

I really hope you understand.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
   <?php
    $matchWith = "# http://videosite.com/id1 http://videosite.com/id2 # # http://videosite.com/id3 http://videosite.com/id4 #";

    preg_match_all('%(#)\shttp://videosite\.com/(\w+)\r{0,1}\shttp://videosite\.com/(\w+)\r{0,1}\s(#)%', $matchWith, $result);
    for($i = 0; $i < count($result[2]); $i++){
       print '<a href="http://videosite.com/'.$result[2][$i].'">
       First Part
       </a>';
       print '<a href="http://videosite.com/'.$result[3][$i].'">
       Second Part
       </a>';     
    }
    ?>
```

Answer assumes that the two arrays have a parallel structure.

EDIT: Changed $i== to $i++

Comment: for loop should say `$i++` instead of `$i==`, but other than that, this is correct.

Comment: Awesome! Just the answer I was looking for! You guys rock! :)

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($result); $i++)
{  
    print '<a href="http://videosite.com/'.$result[$1][2].'">
    First Part
    </a>';        

    print '<a href="http://videosite.com/'.$result[$1][3].'">
    Second Part
    </a>'; 
}
```

Comment: I am not sure because I get an error message. But somebody just posted the answer I was looking for. Still thank you :)